# Why's the button displayed only when refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

I want the logout button to show up only when the user's logged in.  It kind of works now but it's not working the way it should.

With the code below, the logout button shows up when the user's logged in only if the page's refreshed.  That's because upon the `<App/>` component being loaded, the `<Navbar/>` component mounted along with it.

But how can I make it so that even if `<Navbar/>`'s loaded, it can still be possible to manipulate when the button can appear based on if the auth token is not null?

Here's App.js:

```
const App = () => {
let [logoutButtonFlag, setLogoutButtonFlag] = useState(false);
let authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

useEffect(() => {
    if (authToken !== null) {
        setLogoutButtonFlag(true);
    } 
}, [authToken]);

return (
    <>
      <Navbar logoutButtonFlag={logoutButtonFlag}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's Navbar.js:

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
    return ( 
      {!props.logoutButtonFlag ? null : <button className="learn-more">Logout</button>}
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: In which component is the user signing into the app?

Comment: @JacobK it's a login component that I didn't include in my original post.  Is there something I need to do in that component?

Comment: Does that component live as a sibling element to the Navbar in App?

Comment: Please include all relevant code for your question/issue. I don't see where you are (a) updating the token value in localStorage , and (b) where you update the `logoutButtonFlag` state in `App` to toggle the view of the logout button. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

you are providing a non-state variable to the list of states that `useEffect` hook 'listen' to, so it will not run again after you change its value.

```
const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'));
```

and when you update the local storge "token" also update `authToken` to the same value.
and your `useEffect` will retrigger on `authToken` change because now its a state

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (authToken !== null) {
        setLogoutButtonFlag(true);
    } 
}, [authToken]);
```

The reason way only on refresh it was updating is because the value of the "token" in local storage was changed already.

Comment: I kind of get what you mean but then what exactly am I setting in `const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'));`?  In other words, where would I use `setAuthToken()` in this case?

Comment: `setAuthToken` is the function that updates the `authToken` state and every time you use it to update the state react will rerender. If you will assign value to `authToken` like so: `authToken = value` no render will happen. you will need to use it when you change the `localStorage("token")` value

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlvBzyy-558 Here is a great video that explains about hooks

Comment: Right, I understand now.  I tried your example but the same behavior's still being carried out in terms of the logout button showing up only when the page's refreshed.

Comment: you probably need to update the `authToken` state when pressing the login out  button

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what I'm trying to do :) Irrespective of the button's functionality - I just want the button to show/hide correctly depending on if the auth token is null or not

Comment: my bad, you need to update the `logoutButtonFlag` to `null` when the user logs out, like so: `setLogoutButtonFlag(null)`